# protractor, can't get the correct data from session-storage

Tags: javascript, protractor, automated-tests, session-storage

I'm new to protractor and i need to get a data from session storage I need to check the presence of a field. How can i do this? I have to check if logged user have a value for the field "firstCode". Here it is an example of sessionStorage data:

```
{"bookCode":"CNMPPS","agency":"vu","topCode":"HHH4C","firstDate":"14042018","secondDate":"","firstCode":"ROM","secondCode":"ROM","carCode":"RM","market":"","lang":"en","customer":{"FieldNumber":"IKH8272HKS","title":"MR","firstName":"Mark","lastName":"Venium","email":"markvenium@hotmail.com","customerType":"","loyaltyTier":""}}
```

Here's my code `stepdefinitions.js`:

```
var j_userData = browser.driver.executeScript('sessionStorage.getItem("userData");');
var firstCode = JSON.parse(j_userData).firstCode;
expect(firstCode).to.not.be.null;
```

The console returns me this:

```
SyntaxError: Unexpected token M in JSON at position 0
   at JSON.parse (<anonymous>)
```

Can someone help me to take the correct value of the field from sessionStorage? Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

sessionStorage can only store string values. Not sure how you store it with above code and I never used protactor but you can try to stringify your data before storing.
I assume protractor has same code style for storing as well

> to store

```
var jsonData = JSON.stringify({"bookCode":"CNMPPS","agency":"vu","topCode":"HHH4C","firstDate":"14042018","secondDate":"","firstCode":"ROM","secondCode":"ROM","carCode":"RM","market":"","lang":"en","customer":{"FieldNumber":"IKH8272HKS","title":"MR","firstName":"Mark","lastName":"Venium","email":"markvenium@hotmail.com","customerType":"","loyaltyTier":""}});
var j_userData = browser.driver.executeScript('sessionStorage.setItem("userData", ' + jsonData+ ' );');
```

> to receive

```
var j_userData = browser.driver.executeScript('sessionStorage.getItem("userData");');
var firstCode = JSON.parse(j_userData).firstCode;
expect(firstCode).to.not.be.null;
```

Comment: Hi @serdar.sanri, thank you for your answer. I have to reason as if I did not know the content of the sessionstorage, so I can not just copy the whole code and pars it, rather I have to retrieve the sessionstorage data, save it in a variable and then pars it

Comment: I see what you mean. Then it looks like there is something ( possibly a wrong character ) in stored data. Because the error you are getting is in the JSON.parse function that complains one of the keys is invalid that it can't parse the data.

Comment: Can you copy&paste the plain data in sessionStorage, as is stored. Like I mentioned above, sessionStorage can only store string data. ( chrome shows a preview of parsed data if you click on it in debugger, not that one). Just dbl click on  data in session storage as it is and add to your question. Let's see if is there any different characters might be causing this issue

Comment: Hi @serdar.sanri, thank you for your answer and I'm sorry for the late reply. I taken the example of sessionStorage data that I included at the top of my question from the debugger of Chrome and is the "userData". The environment is actually down, but I have to facing the problem the same. Just to make matters worse I have exactly the same error message in an other automated test's project. Surely, i did it in the same way, so it was expactable. How can I do?

Comment: I am wondering if protactor automatically parses the sessionStorage data to json, When I copied the above data, stringify and put in back to sessionStorage, it seems to be working fine and I got `ROM` as a result. See if removing JSON.parse would make any difference in your case. `var firstCode = j_userData.firstCode; `

Answer (score 0):

If you try to access window object / browser scope from protractor directly it will may throw error as "window is not defined" etc because window object / browser scope may not be loaded / defined when you are trying to access it.

Solution

`browser.executeScript('return window.sessionStorage.getItem("myKey");').then(function (myValue) {
    console.log('testcase myValue == ', myValue);
});`

You will get whole object in **myValue** *(console.log('testcase myValue == ', myValue))*.